# XML: How to create valid namespace + xsd schema

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

I've got a problem with configuring XML + XSD. I wanted to use a namespace in my XML, but I don't know how to write a XSD for this.

The 'a' namespace stands for 'actor'. I know it isn't good idea to do something like that, but it's just a excercise :)

If I would use something like

```
<role name="xxx">
    <actorName>asd</actorName>
    ...
</role>
```

etc. it will be valid, but I really wanted  to learn how to use namespaces.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog xmlns:a="actor">
    <movie>
        <title>The Shawshank Redemption</title>
        <year>1994</year>
        <director>Frank Darabont</director>
        <screenplay>Frank Darabont</screenplay>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
        <country>USA</country>
        <description>Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.</description>
        <stars>
            <role name="Andy Dufresne">
                <a:name>Tim Robbins</a:name>
                <a:year>1958</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
            <role name="Ellis Boyd 'Red' Redding">
                <a:name>Morgan Freeman</a:name>
                <a:year>1937</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
            <role name="Warden Norton">
                <a:name>Bob Gunton</a:name>
                <a:year>1945</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
        </stars>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>The Godfather</title>
        <year>1972</year>
        <director>Francis Ford Coppola</director>
        <screenplay>Mario Puzo, Francis Ford Coppola</screenplay>
        <genre>Crime, Drama</genre>
        <country>USA</country>
        <description>The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son.</description>
        <stars>
            <role name="Don Vito Corleone">
                <a:name>Marlon Brando</a:name>
                <a:year>1924</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
            <role name="Michael Corleone">
                <a:name>Al Pacino</a:name>
                <a:year>1940</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
            <role name="Sonny Corleone">
                <a:name>James Caan</a:name>
                <a:year>1940</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
        </stars>
    </movie>
</catalog>
```

And my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="urn:a" >
   <xs:element name="catalog">
   <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="movie" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="year" type="xs:short"/>
           <xs:element name="director" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="screenplay" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="genre" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="description">
               <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                   <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
               </xs:restriction>
               </xs:simpleType>
           </xs:element>
           <xs:element name="stars">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="role" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="year" type="xs:short"/>
                        <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
       </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Can you help me do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
role.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="actor"> 
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="year" type="xs:short"/>
    <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

catalog.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:a = 'actor'>
    <xs:import namespace="actor" schemaLocation="role.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="catalog">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="movie" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="year" type="xs:short"/>
                            <xs:element name="director" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="screenplay" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="genre" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="description">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="stars">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="role" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                  <xs:element ref="a:name"/>
                                                    <xs:element ref="a:year"/>
                                                    <xs:element ref="a:country"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

catalog.xml:

```
    <catalog xmlns:a="actor" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalog.xsd">
    <movie>
        <title>The Shawshank Redemption</title>
        <year>1994</year>
        <director>Frank Darabont</director>
        <screenplay>Frank Darabont</screenplay>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
        <country>USA</country>
        <description>Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.</description>
        <stars>
            <role name="Andy Dufresne">
                <a:name>Tim Robbins</a:name>
                <a:year>1958</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
            <role name="Ellis Boyd 'Red' Redding">
                <a:name>Morgan Freeman</a:name>
                <a:year>1937</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
            <role name="Warden Norton">
                <a:name>Bob Gunton</a:name>
                <a:year>1945</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
        </stars>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>The Godfather</title>
        <year>1972</year>
        <director>Francis Ford Coppola</director>
        <screenplay>Mario Puzo, Francis Ford Coppola</screenplay>
        <genre>Crime, Drama</genre>
        <country>USA</country>
        <description>The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son.</description>
        <stars>
            <role name="Don Vito Corleone">
                <a:name>Marlon Brando</a:name>
                <a:year>1924</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
            <role name="Michael Corleone">
                <a:name>Al Pacino</a:name>
                <a:year>1940</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
            <role name="Sonny Corleone">
                <a:name>James Caan</a:name>
                <a:year>1940</a:year>
                <a:country>USA</a:country>
            </role>
        </stars>
    </movie>
</catalog>
```